# Mapping Json Array to POJO using Jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson-databind

I have a JSON array of the form:

```
[
 [
  1232324343,
  "A",
  "B",
  3333,
  "E"
 ],
 [
  12345424343,
  "N",
  "M",
  3133,
  "R"
 ]
]
```

I want to map each element of the parent array to a POJO using the Jackson library. I tried this:

```
ABC abc = new ABC();
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
JsonNode jsonNode = mapper.readTree(data).get("results");

if (jsonNode.isArray()) {
    for (JsonNode node : jsonNode) {
        String nodeContent = mapper.writeValueAsString(node);
        abc = mapper.readValue(nodeContent,ABC.class);

        System.out.println("Data: " + abc.getA());
    }
}
```

where ABC is my POJO class and abc is the object but I get the following exception:

> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of com.demo.json.model.ABC

EDIT:
My POJO looks like this:

```
class ABC{
    long time;
    String a;
    String b;
    int status;
    String c;
}
```

Can someone suggest a solution for this?

EDIT 2: After consulting a lot of answers on StackOverflow and other forums, I came across one solution. I mapped the returned value of readValue() method into an array of POJO objects.

```
ABC[] abc = mapper.readValue(nodeContent, ABC[].class);
```

But now I am getting a separate exception

> Can not construct instance of ABC: no long/Long-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from Number value (1552572583232)

I have tried the following but nothing worked:
1. Forcing Jackson to use ints for long values using

```
mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.USE_LONG_FOR_INTS, true);
```

2. Using wrapper class Long instead of long in the POJO

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Depends on what your POJO looks like.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen I have added the POJO structure as an edit. Please have a look

Comment: I guess you need `CustomDeserializer`

Comment: nice question, struck since 25 minutes.

Comment: What is a `node` in your case? Why do you generate `JSON` based on it and after this deserialise to `ABC` class?

Comment: I'll make an edit and include some more code

Comment: @MichałZiober Please check out the latest edit in the question

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `ARRAY` shape for this object. You can do that using `JsonFormat` annotation:

```
@JsonFormat(shape = Shape.ARRAY)
class ABC {
```

And deserialise it:

```
ABC[] abcs = mapper.readValue(json, ABC[].class);
```

### EDIT after changes in question.

You example code could look like this:

```
JsonNode jsonNode = mapper.readTree(json);
if (jsonNode.isArray()) {
    for (JsonNode node : jsonNode) {
        String nodeContent = mapper.writeValueAsString(node);
        ABC abc = mapper.readValue(nodeContent, ABC.class);

        System.out.println("Data: " + abc.getA());
    }
}
```

We can use `convertValue` method and skip serializing process:

```
JsonNode jsonNode = mapper.readTree(json);
if (jsonNode.isArray()) {
    for (JsonNode node : jsonNode) {
        ABC abc = mapper.convertValue(node, ABC.class);
        System.out.println("Data: " + abc.getA());
    }
}
```

Or even:

```
JsonNode jsonNode = mapper.readTree(json);
ABC[] abc = mapper.convertValue(jsonNode, ABC[].class);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(abc));
```

Comment: It looks cool. I didn't know it's possible to be achieved just with annotations.

Comment: Unfortunately I couldn't make it work. I also tried with `@JsonPropertyOrder({"time", "a", "b", "status", "c"})` with no joy.

Comment: Just added Lombok's `@Data` to the `ABC` class (which is equivalent to adding getters, setters, default constructor, `equals()` and `hashCode()` methods) and it worked without any issues.

Comment: @cassiomolin, you need to have well defined `POJO` class to make it work.

Comment: @MichałZiober I tried this but it did not work. I am getting the following exception:

Can not deserialize a POJO (of type com.demo.json.model.ABC) from non-Array representation (token: VALUE_NUMBER_INT): type/property designed to be serialized as JSON Array

Comment: @MayankAggarwal, which version of `Jackson` do you use? Do you use `codehaus` or `FasterXML` implementation?

Comment: The FasterXML one

Comment: I tried your method. Got this exception

Can not deserialize instance of ABC[] out of VALUE_STRING token

On some research, I found this solution:
mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY, true);
But then I got this exception:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not construct instance of ABC: no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('[ 1232324343,"A","B",3333,"E"]')

Comment: @MayankAggarwal, you do not need any other configurations on `ObjectMapper`. I tested all above examples and they work properly with only `@JsonFormat(shape = Shape.ARRAY)` annotation. `ABC` class should have be `POJO` with all getters/setters and no-arg constructor.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190363/discussion-between-mayank-aggarwal-and-michal-ziober).

Comment: I had to order the data members in my POJO according to the data I am receiving in the JSON array. Combined with the @JsonFormat annotation, this made my code work

Answer (score 1):

Your json does not map to the pojo that you have defined. For the pojo that you have defined, the json should be of the form below.

```
{ 
  "time:1232324343,
  "a":"A",
  "b":"B",
  "status":3333,
  "c":"E"
}
```