# Mapping dynamic JSON object with unlimited nested structure to Map using JsonAnySetter annotation

Tags: java, json, jackson, deserialization, json-deserialization

I want to map `JSON Object` to `Java` class with custom structure.
For example:

```
public class RestAttributesMappingDTO {
    Map<String, Object> details = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    @JsonAnySetter
    void setDetail(String key, Object value) {
        details.put(key, value);
    }
}
```

As you can see, annotation `@JsonAnySetter` have been used for mapping.

Its ok for any flat structure.

But if I want to map object with unlimited (custom) nested structure?

For example:

```
{
    name: "",
    age: "",
    job: [{
         job1: {  
              title: "",
              ZIP: ""                   
         }
    }]
}
```

Arises recursive algorithm of creating map without `@JsonAnySetter`.

But is there any way to build this unlimited nested map with `Jackson`?

Answer (score 1):

Jackson by default deserialises:

- `JSON Object` to `Map` where keys are `String`-s.
- `JSON Array` to `List` of objects or primitives.

In your example, you can keep like it is but it would need casting and checking types in runtime. Other option is to use `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode` class and method could look like:

```
void setDetail(String key, JsonNode value)
```

But you can even skip this method and `@JsonAnySetter` annotation and use it in class directly:

```
public class RestAttributesMappingDTO {
    private JsonNode details;
    //getters, setters
}
```

`JsonNode` allows to iterate over `key-value` pairs.

See some other related questions:

- [Mapping Json Array to POJO using Jackson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55256971/mapping-json-array-to-pojo-using-jackson/55257426#55257426)
- [How to modify the value of a JsonNode recursively using Jackson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55560223/how-to-modify-the-value-of-a-jsonnode-recursively-using-jackson/55581639#55581639)
- [How to convert a JsonNode instance to an actual pojo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60991716/how-to-convert-a-jsonnode-instance-to-an-actual-pojo/60993355#60993355)